# Pass jQuery list to Python with jsonify and $.getJSON()

Tags: jquery, python, html

I'm looking to pass a *list* created in jQuery based on a multiple select box from HTML to Python.  I know how to pass a single variable from an HTML `<input>` to Python with something like:

`my_variable: $("#option_selected").val()`

And I'm able to create a list with multiple selected options using the following jQuery code:

`var all_options = [];
        $('select[name="option_selected"] > option:selected').each(function() {
                all_options.push($(this).val());
        });`

and I can run an `alert()` that displays all of the correctly selected options.  However, when I execute

`$.getJSON('_get_selected', {`

immediately after that code, I can't figure out how to pass the list back to Python using something similar to the format shown at the top.

I've tried:

`my_list: all_options;
my_list: all_options.val();
my_list: $(all_options).val();
my_list: $('all_options').val();`

and other variations, all with no luck.

UPDATE:

I've created the following godawful hack for the time being:

`my_list: all_options[0] + ',' + all_options[1] + ',' + all_options[2] + ... + all_options[10]`

Then in Python I am then replacing the "undefined" data with blank space, stripping out any other non essential data, splitting it along the commas, and then converting to a list.  Truly horrific.

Luckily I will rarely go above 10 items in the list (and if I think I will, I'll just add them on).  But the question still remains.  This hack shouldn't be necessary.

Does anyone have a more elegant solution?

...and I would love to know how to pass lists the other way as well.